# converting from Javascript to JQuery - Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

Could one kindly advise me how i would write the below javascript in jQuery? i am unsure as my converted code is not working

> application.js

```
document.getElementById("userj_cvattachment").onchange = function () {
  document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};
```

Comment: You don't need to. Just use existing code whats the issue

Comment: Can you share your converted code. We could point you in right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break it down.

1. You select an element by: `document.getElementById("userj_cvattachment")`

   ```
   $("#userj_cvattachment")
   ```
2. You attach a handler to its change event: `.onchange = function (){ }`

   ```
   $("#userj_cvattachment").on("change", function(){ });
   ```
3. You select another element by id
4. You change its value: `.value = this.value;`

   ```
   $("#userj_cvattachment").on("change", function(){ 
       $("#uploadFile").val($(this).val());
   });
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#userj_cvattachment').change(function(){
   $('#uploadFile').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#userj_cvattachment").change(function(e) {
   $("#uploadFile").val($(this).val());
}
```

*$("#whatever")* is your basic selector (by id, use *.whatever* for selecting by class, read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). [Change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) adds the given function as a listener. Inside that listener we use *$(this)* to get the element the change was on. [val](https://api.jquery.com/val/) gets or returns the value depending on whether you pass it a value or not.